# C# Could not load file or assembly vtkRenderingDotNet

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, vtk

My visual studio 2008 show the problem below when i start to drag the `vtkFormsWindowControl`.

I already set the path for it.

Problem :

> Failed to create component 'vtkFormsWindowControl'.The error message
>   follows : 'System.IO.FilterNotFoundException:Could not load file or
>   assembly 'vtkRenderingDotNet, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its depencies.The system cannot find
>   the file specified.

Anyone know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a library file in your solution.

Namely, **vtkRenderingDotNet**.

Find that, and make sure it is part of your Visual Studio solution.

Clean the project (Menu: Debug > Clean) then rebuild it (Menu: Debug > Rebuild).

Comment: vtkRenderingDotNet is existing in my visual studio's debug file.

Comment: VS is telling you the problem. It is looking for **'vtkRenderingDotNet, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies**. You have the wrong version in your project, you are missing one of the dependencies, or the file is not where Visual Studio is looking for it.